# clear both or overflow hidden , a clearfix solution

Tags: css-float, css

I am designing table less website using `div` elements and i have many floated left and right `div` elements inside parent `div` element.

Now, I am using another `div` element to fix parent `div` height automatically:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

But, I came to know following works in same way:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden">
    <div style="float:left">...</div>
    <div style="float:right">...</div>
</div>
```

And , i tried, it works and which reduces the **Number of DOM Elements** as well.

But I don't whether it is **cross-browser** or not.

Which method is effective and cross-browser?

Comment: I bet you could have checked it in the applicable browsers faster than you could have asked this question on StackOverflow.

Comment: asking on StackOverflow with you guys means, knowing your experiences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`overflow:hidden` makes the element establish a new [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting). This fixes the float containment of any children floating within it. This CSS fix is more practical then including an additional element in the HTML styled with `clear:both` and works on all modern browsers, including IE7+.